# Easy way to browse through external jars in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I don't want to use certain library, I just want to browse through its jar (with sources). Is there an easy way of doing this in Intellij? I know this could be done by adding it as a dependency and then marking as a library but as I said this would be kind of unnecessary since I don't really want to make this jar my dependency.

Comment: I think that intellij is automatically decode .class files. so you can browse their content.

Comment: Intellij will show all the jars from your pom files in `external libraries` section, It will not show any other library than from pom file. I don't think there will be any other way to browse code which is some not related to the application at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't browse a library in intellij if it is not referenced in your application. The IDE has no reason to download the jar since you didn't tell it you need it.

That said if you don't want to use the jar in your application as you mentioned, but you just want to browse it's source, you can do the following:

- simply add it to your pom.xml (if it's a maven project)
- Navigate to the 'External Libraries' in the project pane
- Surf around the library package(s) and classes
- Click any desired class to view it's source (IntelliJ decompiles for you)
- Once you're done, surfing around, remove the entry from your pom file (Intellij drops the library from your 'External Libraries' section)

Alternatively, if you want to permanently be able to view the source without the need to delete the pom entry, create a new (separate) maven project and  add the relevant pom entries (dependencies to the pom.xml file), and follow the steps above.

You can always switch to the 'new project' window whenever you want to browse the sources of the library.

NB: The process you described as:

> I know this could be done by adding it as a dependency and then
>   marking as a library

makes it sound more 'complex' than it is. All you have to do is add the pom entry and the IDE takes care of the rest.